# Amcharts 4 EventDispatcher is disposed error

Tags: typescript, amcharts4

I use angular and AmCharts 4. When I dispose chart and then create chart again I got "EventDispatcher is disposed"

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
        // Chart code goes in here
        this.browserOnly(() => {
            const config = _.assign({}, this.config, {
                data: this.data
            });

            am4core.createDeferred(() => {
                this.chart = am4core.createFromConfig(config, this.chartContainerEl.nativeElement);
                return this.chart;
            }).then((chart) => {
            });
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // Clean up chart when the component is removed
        this.browserOnly(() => {
            if (this.chart) {
                this.chart.dispose();
            }
        });
    }
```

How I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution (we need copy config)

> A config that we use to create a chart might, and probably will get
> mutated by the JSON processor, replacing and filling properties with
> references with real chart objects. This makes a config that was
> already used for one chart, not usable for creating another chart.
>
> If you need to use same config object to cookie-cut charts, make sure
> you use "copies" of the config rather than same object.
>
> There are many methods to copy JS objects. Probably the most
> wide-spread and simple one is using JSON object in JavaScript:

```js
function cloneJSON(source) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source));
}

let chart1 = am4core.createFromConfig(cloneJSON(config), ....);
let chart2 = am4core.createFromConfig(cloneJSON(config), ....);
```